# iOS App that Shares location data

Tags: ios, authentication, location, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to design an app that has a core functionality of allowing users to share their location data but I have no idea how to start. Basically when the app is on you will be able to see the location of certain people you are connected to in real time. There is more to it than that but that is just the main feature I am having trouble with.

Can anyone give me some ideas of what technologies or SDK's might be helpful? I was using the Facebook SDK so I wouldn't have to build a whole login system but I am not sure that helps in the location department.

Any ideas of where to start? Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides a class `CLLocationManager` for tracking the location. Here is the demo code from Apple which might be helpful in getting you started.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html

And `CLLocationManager` class reference

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

Comment: Thanks! How would I share this information between two phones?

Comment: @Seuby: You can use an intermediate server to log the location details and share the data between between devices.

Comment: Thanks! Can you maybe give me some example technologies I might use or point me in the right direction?